# unable to load offline map using Mapsui, using world.mbtiles

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapsui

var layer = new TileLayer(new MbTilesTileSource(new SQLiteConnectionString(dbPath,true), null, MbTilesType.None, true, true));
and adding this layer to map

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't formatted your code, and you haven't given a good description of the problem you're trying to solve.  Do you get an error or exception?  Are there any useful console messages displayed?  Are you sure your `dbPath` is valid?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Mapsui repository has a working sample that shows the world.mbtiles. You could start from that working sample and work towards your own application in steps.

Clone the [Mapsui repository](https://github.com/mapsui/mapsui). Set Mapsui.Samples.Wpf (or one of the other sample projects) as startup project. Run, select the 'Data' category at the top left, and it will show the mbtiles map.

Note, that the wpf sample has the world.mbtiles included with *Build Action* as 'Content' and *Copy to Output Directory* as 'Copy if Newer'. Deployment of the mbtiles file to the right location could be your problem.